# How to enhance attr_accessor in ruby?

Tags: ruby, attributes, metaprogramming, attr-accessor

I want to implement a (class) method `attr_accessor_with_client_reset`, which does the same thing as `attr_accessor`, but on every writer it additionally executes

```
@client = nil
```

So, for example,

```
attr_accessor_with_client_reset :foo
```

should produce the same result as

```
attr_reader :foo

def foo=(value)
  @foo = value
  @client = nil
end
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, I did, but I guess I did a typo, because it works now when I tried it again. You're right, I should've posted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sergio's solution is good, but needlessly complex: there's no need to duplicate the behavior of `attr_reader`, you can just delegate to it. And there's no need for all this double module include hook hackery. Plus, `attr_accessor` takes multiple names, so `attr_accessor_with_client_reset` should, too.

```
module AttrAccessorWithClientReset
  def attr_accessor_with_client_reset(*names)
    attr_reader *names

    names.each do |name|
      define_method :"#{name}=" do |v|
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", v)
        @client = nil
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend AttrAccessorWithClientReset

  attr_reader :client
  def initialize
    @foo = 0
    @client = 'client'
  end

  attr_accessor_with_client_reset :foo
end

f = Foo.new
f.foo    # => 0
f.client # => "client"
f.foo = 1
f.foo    # => 1
f.client # => nil
```

Comment: Sorry, the `base.extend ClassMethods` is coming out automatically :) +1'd

Comment: BTW, `define_method` and co are accepting strings as well as symbols. Why are you using symbols here? To me it's unnecessary visual noise.

Comment: I guess they are just coming out automatically :-) `Symbol`s represent names. Actually, they represent entries in the Ruby interpreter's/compiler's symbol table. Which is exactly what a method name is. So, to me, it just feels semantically "right". It's probably more a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty straightforward if you have some experience in ruby metaprogramming. Take a look:

```
module Ext
  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def attr_accessor_with_client_reset name
      define_method name do
        instance_variable_get "@#{name}"
      end

      define_method "#{name}=" do |v|
        instance_variable_set "@#{name}", v
        @client = nil
      end
    end
  end

end

class Foo
  include Ext

  attr_reader :client
  def initialize
    @foo = 0
    @client = 'client'
  end

  attr_accessor_with_client_reset :foo
end

f = Foo.new
f.foo # => 0
f.client # => "client"
f.foo = 1
f.foo # => 1
f.client # => nil
```

If this code is not completely clear to you, then I strongly recommend this book: [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby).