# Can we extend attr_accessor in ruby with other properties like checking the status of variable?

Tags: ruby

How can we extend attr_accessor. is it possible?

Comment: Can you show me some example.I am not getting what to be done.

Comment: http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html

This might help you a bit!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410391/how-to-enhance-attr-accessor-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the basic formula for extending it for a class would be like this:

```
class SomeClass

   def self.attr_accessor(param)

    ...some code...


   end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking an instance variable, attr_reader will suffice. You do not need attr_accessor.